# Is it possible to lose a badge during a recalc?

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to lose badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/is-it-possible-to-lose-badges)

Is it possible to lose a badge during a recalc? Or once you have it you can't lose it?

Comment: Which question are you asking? Helps to pin down your dupe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You won't lose the badge, but the next time you get that badge your number won't go up either.  You'll have to reaccumulate them before your total starts incrementing again.

Comment: Note: This is now outdated.