# Is it possible to lose badges?

Tags: support, badges, revoked-badges

Is it possible to lose badges after they've been awarded?

Comment: Heh, I was going to point to [the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) but it turns out this question isn't addressed there. Guess I'll upvote instead.

Comment: You may, but you cannot ♪

Comment: @mmyers I worked this into the FAQ.

Answer (score 52):

No, badges are never taken away.  That's part of the site's design.

However, if you no longer meet the criteria for a badge (say your "great question" got busted back down to 99 votes), then you won't earn another one of those badges until you "catch up."

Comment: Just to get this straight: Does "until you catch up" mean you can get another badge for meeting the same criteria *again* on the same post?

Comment: @Tomalak: That's an interesting question and I believe you technically *can*.  If you get upvoted 100 times on a question, then slip back to 99, then get 100 upvotes on a *different* question, you won't get the badge for the second question.  But if you then get back to 100 votes on the *first* question, I think that the second badge is awarded *then*.  I'm not sure how it works internally; now that the system tells you which question a badge was awarded for (if applicable), it would be interesting to test this out and see if the second badge is linked to the second question or first.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58088/can-the-same-bade-be-awarded-two-times-in-this-situation

Comment: It used to be possible for there to be a mismatch between the question it says you got a badge for and the question you actually got it for, but it was fixed in 2013: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81013/nice-answer-badge-roulette/187740#187740

Comment: "never taken away" is wrong. they're taken away if they were acquired by heinous cheating

Answer (score 32):

*General* badges will not be taken away once you have earned them (barring very exceptional circumstances).

*Tag* badges, on the other hand, will be revoked if you don't meet the criteria for them anymore. If you earned a bronze badge in a certain tag for 20 non-wiki answers with a total score of exactly 100, and then one of your answers gets downvoted (bringing your total score to 99), you will lose the tag badge.

Answer (score 6):

No, once they are awarded they are never taken away.

Comment: He's lying. Ten minutes ago, @Juan had 21 silver badges. I took one and gave it to those in need.

Comment: hahahah, really, how? cuz I wan... I mean... I need one.

Comment: @Luiscencio - Ultra ninja badge burgling skills (I said psst, look over there! then swiped one while he was distracted)

Comment: @Tim change your name to "Badge Burgling-er"