# Can the same badge be awarded two times in this situation?

Tags: discussion, badges

Simple thought experiment (provoked by the comments on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/may-i-lose-a-badge/58055#58055)),

- A question crosses the 10 up-votes barrier.
- The "Nice Question" badge is awarded.
- Someone down-votes the question to 9.
- Random stuff happens (any length of time passes, other badges are awarded, whatever)
- The question gets up-voted again
- ?
- profit

Will "Nice Question" be awarded a second time?

Comment: This wasn't *quite* the situation I proposed; you left out the part where a second question is submitted and gets upvoted 10 times, but *doesn't* get the badge because the first question is no longer eligible.  Obviously a new badge is awarded once *both* questions reach 10 upvotes; the mystery is whether the second badge will be attached to the first question or the second one.  Is the system smart enough to remember that the badge that's about to be awarded really belongs to a totally different question?

Comment: @Aarobot: Okay, that's a different situation indeed. But what I originally meant was what I wrote here. I was quite, but not entirely certain that a badge would not be awarded again, I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Ladybug: Nice edit.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, badges are not removed from your account when you no longer meet the critera, but you will not gain any new badges until the 'undeserved" badge slots are filled.

1. I get a badge for +10 post (My profile shows 1, I meet critera for 1)
2. I get a downvote. (My profile shows 1, I meet critera for 0)
3. I produce a second +10 post (My profile shows **1**, I meet criteria for 1)
4. I get an upvote on the original (My profile shows 2, I meet criteria for 2)

So it only increments the number in your profile when you increase the number that you "deserve" according to the back end.

The [Badges FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) [says it better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work/17854#17854).

> When badges are awarded, the system checks to see how many you're supposed to have, and only awards new badges when the number of badges you're supposed to have is greater than the number of badges you have.

Comment: That's interesting. I never knew the 'X nn' worked that way.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is only awarded one time for one question. But it is not revoked, when falling back to 9 votes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Badges aren't ever taken away, but the number you should have is checked when the process runs, so you won't earn a new badge if you already have one that you shouldn't.