# Can a badge be un-awarded?

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)
>   [May I lose a badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/may-i-lose-a-badge)

For example, the Convention badge requires 10 posts with a score of 2 or more on meta. What happens if, after you get the badge, two of your posts get downvoted so you have less than 10 posts with score 2 or more?

Or, another example, the Electorate badge requires 600 votes on questions, and more than 25% of the total votes should be on questions. What happens if, after attaining the Electorate badge, you go on an answer voting spree and bring down the percentage to below 25?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you keep a badge even if you no longer meet the criteria.  (Exception:  tag badges)

I found this question and the first answer explains badges in great detail: [How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

Comment: The exceptions are the tag badges. If you fall below the required vote/answer score you'll lose the badge.