# Can I forbear a badge?

Tags: support, badges

Pretty much what the title says, but I think context is needed.

I already read [Is it possible to lose badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/may-i-lose-a-badge), by the way, but this one is not a case of one no longer fulfilling the criteria but rather, at least in my opinion, never having met the criteria in the first place.

At stackoverflow.com, I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495428/boosttribool-odd-behaviour-or-bug/5998816#5998816) about C++. I originally intended to comment on one of the existing answers (the *one* existing answer, technically), but either couldn't find (after three minutes) a button or link to do that, or I do not have the required privileges to comment answers yet. Thus I opted for adding my comment as an answer.

When I posted the answer, the page notified me that I have earned the "Teacher Badge" for "answering a question with rank +1 or more" (not exact wording). With it, I also got some privileges such as chat mode. However, what I did does not technically count as answering the question, as it was a comment on an existing question -- the question itself is, already, answered. For that I feel it is kinda unfair that I have earned the badge and privileges, so I'd like to ask if there is a way to un-award the badge, remove the privileges or something.

Unfortunately I'm not that self-criticizing as to downvote my own answer, and besides it is possible the site awards me with *yet another badge* if I did it anyway, thus adding to the irony.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, but you shouldn't worry about it, especially for such a trivial badge -- you'd "earn" it for real the next time you posted an answer that got upvoted, which has already happened. In the case of a badge that gets awarded multiple times (e.g. [Nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer)), if you delete the answer you'll keep the badge, but you won't be awarded one the next time you should earn it, so even those balance out in the end

Comment: Upvoted....? Aww come on! When did *that* happen? (j/k) I was refreshing that tab like crazy, just in case... Anyway, thanks for the pointers; I didn't know about balanceable badges. Will wait a little more and see if there are more comments before ticking your as Accepted.