# Rewards maintained after undone

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, reputation, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to lose badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/is-it-possible-to-lose-badges)

Rewards maintained when what triggered them in undone.

***First case.***

More specific I earned a badge because of a down vote I made,I earned the `Critic Badge` but when I decided to undo the vote the badge still remained.

***Second Case.***

Some weeks ago I was rewarded with 100 reputation point because my reputation points has raise to 200 within one year.What triggered that was a users decision to choice my answer as the proper one,when he regret it I lost the 30 point of the selected answer but the 100 bonus remained.

Comment: Both cases are by design.

Comment: @Yannis Thanks kardasi.

Comment: The dupe is correct for case 1, but I think this is the first time anyone has reported case 2.

Comment: @Pop it still seems by design though - I'm assuming he means the association bonus that was given despite two unaccepts pushing his rep below 200 on the first site he was on

Comment: @Pekka I agree, I'm just saying that the association bonus isn't a badge, so I'm not willing to vote to close as "exact duplicate."

Comment: @Pop fair enough, true.