# Can we lose badges? Bug or not?

Tags: discussion, badges, merge-accounts

I changed my email on Stack Overflow. And after that, I received back a lot of badges but not all.

For example, I lost `Quorum` and `Constituent`.

And I had one more silver badge and one other bronze badge but I don't remember which one.

So my question is: is it a bug, or are the answers to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/is-it-possible-to-lose-badges) (last one in 2012) deprecated?

And if it's normal, can we add a warning when we want to change our e-mail?

(I don't want to have my badges back, I just want clarify this thing).

Comment: Was the new e-mail address associated with a Stack Exchange account before the change?

Comment: As the answer in the dupe says, the email change triggered automatic account merge, hence all the badges were lost indeed. They do get back, but on instantly and not all of them.